# Datasheet for Taos TCS3200 GY-31

Tags: sensors

Can someone please post the datasheet for the colour sensor mentioned above. All i can find is for TCS3200

Comment: You may have better luck on electronics. This falls into the cracks between a good and bad question though.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I find helpful for minimal or missing datasheets is to look for Arduino/PIC or other code examples and discussions on the module. The basic datasheet has wiring - but no actual usage help, where as forum discussions and code examples will get you some actual results from it. [This one](http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php/136258-Code-for-using-a-TCS3200-with-Arduino-and-a-question) looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the *TCS230* or the *TCS3200*?
If its the *TCS3200 GY-31* (which is the upgraded module from the *TCS230*), you can try [this](http://smart-prototyping.com/image/data/2_components/Arduino/100847%20GY-31%20TCS230%20TCS3200%20Color%20Sensor%20Recognition%20Module%20for%20Arduino/color-sensor-module.pdf).

Its not the most informative, but it does cover the basics for the *GY-31*.